# Specify threads to Celery in case of many Queues executed

Tags: python, multithreading, centos, celery, supervisord

It's been almost over two years that i use Celery in Production Web/Server with Django. It's been almost over two years that i search without success a solution to this problem : "How specify the numbers of threads available to celery ?"

I have 32 Threads on my production Server and 7 Celery Queues.

I use Celery on Centos OS managed by `Supervisord` like this

#### celery.ini

```
[program:Site_Web_celery-worker1]
command=/etc/supervisord.d/celery-worker1.sh
directory=/var/www/html/SiteWeb/Site_Web/
user=apache
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker1.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker1.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
priority=999
stopasgroup=true
```

The celery command line for the 1 first Queue.

```
celery -A Site_Web.celery_settings worker -l info --autoscale 22 -Q default -n worker1.%h
```

### In resume:

*How can i just specify at Celery to work only on the 30 first Threads and never use the 2 last Threads ?*

Thanks in advance for any help and tips.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you want to set CPU affinity for every worker-process spawned by Celery. Celery does not support setting CPU affinity for its worker-processes and to do this manually you would have to spend large amount of time writing a monitoring tool that constantly "watches" Celery worker and its child processes and sets up CPU affinity using [taskset](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/taskset.1.html) or something similar.

I personally believe it is not worth the effort. *Good* reasons for setting CPU affinity are rare - trust your system's scheduler.

Comment: Okay, i understand your meaning. I think the most effective action to do is to separate the web site off the celery workers on different machine server. I have recently look up on `cgroups` in Centos, can i achive my initial goal with that kind of system tool ?